# Prove the following geometric inequality.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, problem-solving, area

Let $P$ be a point in triangle $ABC$.

Prove that :
$AP+BP+CP>2\sqrt[2]{\sqrt[2]{3}S}$
Such that $S$ is the area of the triangle.

I can only prove that if $P$ is a point inside any triangle $\Delta ABC$ then we have the following inequality(which I have proved using triangle inequality) ; $$s\leq AP+BP+CP\leq 2s,$$ where $s$ is the semi perimeter of the triangle. How can I solve the given problem. Thank you!

Comment: It's wrong for an equilateral triangle

Comment: Can you prove or disprove the statement @Michael Rozenberg ?

Comment: It' wrong for $a=b=c$ and P is a center of s triangle. I solved your problem for $\geq$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard notation we'll prove that $$R_a+R_b+R_c\geq\sqrt{2\sqrt3S}
$$
Indeed, let $\measuredangle{PAC}\leq120^{\circ}.$

Also, let $R_{A}^{60^{\circ}}$ is a rotation around $A$ by the angle $60^{\circ},$$ R_{A}^{60^{\circ}}(P)=P'$ and $R_{A}^{60^{\circ}}(B)=B'$.

Thus, by the triangle inequality $$R_a+R_b+R_c=PA+PB+PC=PP'+P'B'+PC\geq B'C=$$
$$=\sqrt{c^2+b^2-2bc\cos\measuredangle{B'AC}}=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\cos\left(60^{\circ}+\alpha\right)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{b^2+c^2-2bc\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cdot\frac{2S}{bc}\right)}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$b^2+c^2-2bc\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cdot\frac{2S}{bc}\right)\geq4\sqrt3S$$ or
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq4\sqrt3S$$ or
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq\sqrt{3\sum_{cyc}(2a^2b^2-a^4)}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^2-b^2)^2\geq0.$$
If $\measuredangle{PAC}>120^{\circ}.$

So $R_a+R_b+R_c>b+c$ and it remans to prove that:
$$(b+c)^2>4\sqrt{3}S.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Yes , now I get it. Thank you very much @Michael Rozenberg.